# Google Sheets Query a table of sales data and multiply 2 columns together as shown

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

Can you help with this please.
I have a large sales data table as shown below. I'd like to QUERY that with the desired results shown below it. Note that as sales are tallied up for each sales rep, I'd like to list the sum of items sold by a Rep and the average price at which he/she sold the items.
Hence, i need it to multiply No. Items column by Item Price and divide the sum by the total number of items sold by THAT same rep.
Is this possible? I hope this format below helps. Thank you.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRxDikVd3YYKg-lsEYuic7niSUqTK6zx0jCQkQPb4LBhDNrrcxtoniVgs31vthj5cCug6nVnX1520zA/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

```
Sales Rep      Date     No. Items     Item Price
John           5/2/23           22        $9.00
Steve          5/5/23           18   $10.00
Mary           5/22/23          26    $9.50
John           5/24         14    $8.90
Mary           6/1/23           32   $12.00
Steve          6/5/23           11   $11.00
John           6/15/23          28   $10.25
```

Desired Results

```
Sales Rep   Date    No. Items   Avg. Item Price
John         5/2/23 64          $9.53
Steve        5/5/23 29          $10.38
Mary         5/22/23    58          $10.88
```